# Keeps returning this error - System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.'

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database

I am having trouble registering to my data base. It keeps returning this error

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.'

```
if (Request.Form["RegisterSubmit"] != null)
        {

        string FirstName_t = Request.Form["FirstName"]; // firt name
        string LastName_t = Request.Form["LastName"]; // last name
        string Email_t = Request.Form["Email"]; // Email
        string Password_t = Request.Form["psw"]; // password
        int YearBorn_t = int.Parse(Request.Form["Bday"]); // Birth year
        string FavoriteZones = Request.Form["Favorite"]; // favorite places`
        string Location = Request.Form["Zone"]; // Where the user lives 
                                          
        string SqlCom = string.Format("INSERT INTO DB (FirstName, LastName, Email, psw, Favorite, Bday, Zone) VALUES ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', '{4}', {5}, '{6}')", FirstName_t, LastName_t, Email_t, Password_t, FavoriteZones, YearBorn_t, Location);
        MyAdoHelperAccess.DoQuery(SqlCom);
```

Comment: Most likely one of your variables contains a value that evaluates to improper sql. That is just one of the very good reasons to build parameterized queries instead sql strings.

Comment: if you debug your code what would be value of "SqlCom" before you execute it , paste it here

Comment: If any of your inputs include a single quote, it will blow up. And if anyone's name is "Bobby');drop table db--" then you'll blow up.

Comment: Wahoo, you take details straight out of a web form and concat them into an SQL.. that is just asking to get hacked. Which bank do you work for?

Comment: Are you writing to Acess or SQL Server?  Usually you use SQLClient for SQL server.  Your error is oleDb.  So what is the connection string?